# onFailure: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $[0]

Tags: java, kotlin

Im trying to parse this API but I don't think my data classes are set up correctly

Connected Sleeper API

```
package com.example.drafttime.api

import com.example.drafttime.data.PlayerData
import com.example.drafttime.data.PlayerInfo
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET


// This file is our interface with the Sleeper api to get player data
interface ConnectedSleeper {

    @GET("nflTeamDataArray")
    fun getPlayerData(
    ):Call<List<PlayerData>>
    companion object{

        private const val BASE_URL =  "http://10.0.2.2:8080/"
        fun create(): ConnectedSleeper {

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ConnectedSleeper::class.java)

        }
    }
}
```

PlayerData.kt data class

```
package com.example.drafttime.data

import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)

data class PlayerData(

  val team: List<Player>


):java.io.Serializable
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)

data class Player(
  val player: List<PlayerInfo>

):java.io.Serializable
```

PlayerInfo.kt

```
package com.example.drafttime.data

import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass


@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)

data class PlayerInfo(
    @Json(name = "birth_date") val birthDate: String?,
@Json(name = "full_name") val fullName: String?,
@Json(name = "college") val college: String?,
@Json(name = "team") val team : String?,
@Json(name = "position") val postion: String?,
@Json(name = "number") val number: Int?,
@Json(name = "age") val age: String?,
@Json(name = "weight") val weight: String?,
@Json(name = "height") val height: String?
):java.io.Serializable
```

MainActivity

```
sleeperConnect.getPlayerData()


    .enqueue(object : Callback<List<PlayerData>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<PlayerData>>,
            response: Response<List<PlayerData>>
        ) {
            ///Need to hook up adapter to this part of the response
            if (response.isSuccessful) {



                Log.d("Response", "onResponse: ${response.body()}")
                //TODO: Adapter and recycler view should go here
               // val adapter = response.body()?.let { it1 -> CustomAdapter(it1) }
               // recyclerview.adapter = adapter





            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<PlayerData>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Draft time Activity ", "onFailure: " + t.message)
        }
    })
```

JSON file

```
[
  [
    {
      "rotoworld_id": 4502,
      "practice_description": null,
      "birth_state": null,
      "metadata": null,
      "espn_id": 11122,
      "birth_country": null,
      "team": "ARI",
      "search_last_name": "prater",
      "player_id": "17",
      "gsis_id": "00-0023853",
      "age": 38,
      "sportradar_id": "67f5e782-f91c-4536-9818-cf4a0e7e821d",
      "last_name": "Prater",
      "status": "Active",
      "fantasy_data_id": 549,
      "yahoo_id": 8565,
      "pandascore_id": null,
      "search_rank": 141,
      "position": "K",
      "birth_city": null,
      "depth_chart_position": "PK",
      "practice_participation": null,
      "sport": "nfl",
      "search_full_name": "mattprater",
      "injury_start_date": null,
      "rotowire_id": 5051,
      "hashtag": "#mattprater-NFL-ARI-5",
      "swish_id": 218237,
      "high_school": "Estero (FL)",
      "number": 5,
      "depth_chart_order": 1,
      "full_name": "Matt Prater",
      "injury_body_part": null,
      "search_first_name": "matt",
      "years_exp": 17,
      "height": "70",
      "first_name": "Matt",
      "injury_status": null,
      "active": true,
      "news_updated": 1678853455354,
      "weight": "201",
      "birth_date": "1984-08-10",
      "fantasy_positions": [
        "K"
      ],
      "stats_id": 218237,
      "college": "UCF",
      "injury_notes": null
    }
  ]
]
```

The JSON file seems to be an Array of objects inside an array. I thought I had set the data classes up correctly but I am getting a the Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $[0]. Am I doing something wrong setting up the data classes?

I tried setting the response from the api to call List<PlayerData> and then List<PlayerInfo> because its an array of objects inside an array but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is nested 2 array and inside 1 object. Try to get response with nested arrays:

```
@GET("nflTeamDataArray")
    fun getPlayerData(
    ):Call<List<List<PlayerData>>>
```

And change other parts of the code to suit this structure. This should give you object directly.